# Unknown error in changing Rstudio appearance

Tags: windows, rstudio, appearance

There is an unknown error when I try to change appearance of Rstudio. It appears when I click "Ok" or "Apply". The appearance will change after this error is passed, but the next time I open the Rstudio, the appearance will change back to default. Is there any way to find out what's wrong? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated RStudio to the latest version?

Comment: Yes. This is the latest version of RStudio

Comment: Than I would file an issue on their github repo